# finished Josephus-Problem in C#, how to make this more efficient?

Tags: c#, beginner

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Function_JosephusSurvivor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Debug purposes
            Console.WriteLine(JosSurvivor(7, 3));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        //Actual function:
        public static int JosSurvivor(int n, int k)
        {
            // n = amount of people(array size)
            // k = every k'th index will be yeeted

            List<int> list = new List<int>();
            int iCounter = 1; //always count till the size of the list
            int iWatcher = 1; //always count till the size of k
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                list.Add(i);
            }

            do
            {

                if (iWatcher+1 == k)
                {
                    list.RemoveAt(iCounter);
                    iWatcher = 0;
                }

                iWatcher++;
                iCounter++;

                if (iCounter == list.Count) // -1 because index
                {
                    iCounter = 0;
                }
                else if (iCounter > list.Count)
                {
                    iCounter = 1; //if one is jumped due to deleteting
                }

            } while (list.Count != 1);

            return list[0]; //winner
        }
    }
}
```

My question is:

### how could you make this more efficient? What could I do better?

I'm trying to submit this as my solution on a practicing page. Unfortunately, it always times out. Therefore I need to make this more efficient I believe.

Thanks in advance :)!

Also feel free to add fitting Tags :)!

Comment: From what aspect are you looking for a more efficient solution? It was executed less than a sec on dotnetfiddle.

Comment: @PeterCsala Maybe something that is better practice, or just any hints on what I could do better :). Also, could it be then, that the website could just have problems at the moment?

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it. From what perspective are you looking for some better solution? Better for maintainability / portability / readability / robustness / more efficient memory usage / ... / ???

Comment: More efficient :)

Comment: Generally speaking you can opt either for time or for resource consumption. What resource consumption is too high in your case?

Comment: There's no need to work through an elimination process.  See: https://www.exploringbinary.com/powers-of-two-in-the-josephus-problem/

Comment: @RickDavin thx for the info! :)

Comment: @PeterCsala what is good practice in order to have a little less memory consumption? And maybe also a faster way of doing this?

Comment: @JeremiasT. Generally speaking in order to reduce the memory usage you have several techniques. Here are some well-known: 1) If possible prefer `Array`s over `List`s, because of double capacity allocation. Or it might be even better to use `IEnumerable`s  2) Try to use `struct`s instead of `class`es for short-living small data objects. 3) Try to avoid to allocate space more than 85000 bytes for a single object, because they will be allocated on the LargeObjectHeap. 4) Try to use allocation optimised structures like `Span`, `Memory`, `ArrayPool`, `StringBuilder`, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
>  List<int> list = new List<int>();
>         int iCounter = 1; //always count till the size of the list
>         int iWatcher = 1; //always count till the size of k
>         for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
>         {
>             list.Add(i);
>         }
> ```

You can initialize `list` more elegantly:

```
List<int> list = Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToList();
```

---

For `n = 2; k = 1` it runs infinitely?

---

Your counting and indexing seem ok, but are a little difficult to comprehend. It can be done a lot easier using modular operations:

```
static int JosSurvivor(int n, int k)
{
  List<int> positions = Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToList();
  int index = k % n - 1; // %n is important for k > n

  while (positions.Count > 1)
  {
    if (index < 0) index += positions.Count;  // when (index + k) % poisitons.Count == 0 then index becomes -1 from the line below
    positions.RemoveAt(index);
    index = (index + k) % positions.Count - 1;
  }

  return positions[0];
}
```

---

Another approach building on the same principle is to maintain a fixed array of indices and then left-shift the reminder of the indices for each found index while decrement n by 1:

```
static int JosSurvivor(int n, int k)
{
  int[] positions = Enumerable.Range(1, n).ToArray();
  int index = k % n - 1;

  while (n > 1)
  {
    if (index < 0) index += n;
    Array.Copy(positions, index + 1, positions, index, n - index - 1);
    n--;
    index = (index + k) % n - 1;
  }

  return positions[0];
}
```

There seems to be a little performance gain - but not significant.

---

Yet another version that uses a fixed array of flags, that are set for each found index:

```
static int JosSurvivor(int n, int k)
{
  int counter = 0;
  int index = -1;
  int runner = 0;
  bool[] positions = new bool[n];

  while (counter < n - 1)
  {
    runner += k;
    int temp = 0;
    do
    {
      index = (index + 1) % n;
    } while (positions[index] || ++temp < k);

    if (runner > 0 && runner % k == 0)
    {
      positions[index] = true;
      counter++;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (!positions[i])
      return i + 1;
  }

  throw new InvalidOperationException("No last position found");
}
```

This is very fast for small `k`s - even for large `n`s - but becomes slower when `k` increases.

Comment: You may have missed my comment to OP, but there is no to work through an elimination process.  A formula may be used instead.  See https://www.exploringbinary.com/powers-of-two-in-the-josephus-problem/

Comment: @RickDavin: I havn't missed your comment, but as far as I can read, it's about eliminating every other person (k = 2) only - not an arbitrary interval - for instance k = 3, og maybe I have missed something?

Comment: @HenrikHansen Thank you! That helped a lot :)!

Answer (score 2):

I just found a really clever solution to this (not mine):

All credit goes to ViolaCrellin:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class JosephusSurvivor
{
    public static int JosSurvivor(int n, int k)
    {
        if (n == 1)
          return 1;
        else
          return (JosSurvivor(n - 1, k) + k-1) % n + 1;
     }
}
```

Very nice solution :)!

**Thanks for the answers everyone!**

---

**Updated** by Henrik Hansen

This is an implementation of the [formula on wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)

Recursive functions always has the potential to overflow the stack, so whenever you can, you should convert it to an iterative approach, which is also almost faster than using recursion:

```
public static int JosSurvivor(int n, int k)
{
  int result = 1;
  for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
  {
    result = (result + k - 1) % i + 1;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but you did not review the original code at all. Reviewing code is all this site is about.

Comment: The person who replied here with the alternative solution IS the OP.

Answer (score 1):

As a beginner you do need to practice the loop-based method, but I'd like to add that when you want to optimize code to the maximum, it's worth looking for mathematical rules that will help you predict things - if something is predictable then there's no need to simulate all the intermediate steps.

For `k = 1` the result is always `n`.

I found a great explanation about the math of this problem for `k = 2` ([link](https://www.exploringbinary.com/powers-of-two-in-the-josephus-problem/)):

$$(2(n-2^{\lfloor\log_2n\rfloor})+1) \mod n$$

In binary, powers of 2 have only one 1-bit, so the part of the formula that finds the greatest power of 2 that is less than or equal to `n` can be replaced with code that finds the left most 1-bit of `n`. It's a micro-optimization but it's related to the point I want to make.

I failed generalizing it to work with any `k`, but it was still worth a shot, my goal is to illustrate that you can use math can optimize some of your code.

Comment: In case `k > n` or even `k < 0`, I would use `k = k % n;`

Comment: Have you actually tested your formula against different steps (k's) - for instance if n = 7 and k = 3? Be aware, that k in OP's algorithm is not the same as k in this formula. Please show the formula implemented in C# with some working examples :-)

Comment: Or I mean the k from the explanation of the formula rather.

Comment: @HenrikHansen I just tested it and it doesn't work, troubleshooting it right now.

Comment: Turns out I made a big mistake when trying to generalize it to cases where `k ≠ 2`, so I replaced it with the cases of `k=1` and `k=2`.

Comment: @potato: [There are 10 types of people...](https://www.exploringbinary.com/there-are-10-types-of-people/) :-)

Comment: @HenrikHansen haha I'd like to think I'm type 1 but sometimes I slip up and act like type 10

Comment: @potato Thank you for the tipp! I will redo this with a formula :).